# input & target tensors for recurrent neural network in tensorflow and optimal TBPTT

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, backpropagation

I have a few fundamental questions about RNNs in tensorflow (v1.3 at time of writing).

I have a pretty solid understanding of RNNs (+LSTM) I think. Amongst other things I've read [Sutskever's PhD Thesis](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~ilya/pubs/ilya_sutskever_phd_thesis.pdf), [Grave's Generating Sequences](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0850) and quite a few other papers/articles. My question is more about usage in tensorflow and how to setup the input/target tensors to do Truncated BackPropagation Through Time (TBPTT).

Say I want to train an RNN to predict next item (like char-rnn).

i.e. learn `P(x_{t+1} | x_{t-n:t})` where n is a maximum sequence length. This is effectively `P(x_{t+1} | x_t, c_t, h_t)` where `c_t, h_t` are `cell state` and `hidden state` at timestep `t`.

It seems most logical to me that (assuming I want to learn dependencies **upto a maximum of n timesteps**):

Method 1 (TBPTT(n, 1):

- if my corpus is L items long (e.g. 10000), I would chunk that into (L-n) mini-sequences (or buckets) each n items long (e.g. 50), moving each bucket 1 item along
- my input tensor would be [batch_size, n, x_dim]
- my target tensor would be [batch_size, **1**, y_dim] # y_dim is dim of pdf for x
- my hidden state tensor(s) would be [batch_size, cell_size] * num_layers (* 2 if LSTM)
- at the start of each **batch** I would zero the state. I would even randomise the order of the buckets on each epoch.

So if my entire corpus is the alphabet (ABC...XYZ), and n is 5, my training pairs are:

- [A,B,C,D,E] -> [F]
- [B,C,D,E,F] -> [G]
- [C,D,E,F,G] -> [H]

etc. and then these are batched up.

HOWEVER, all of the examples I've seen (e.g. https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow, https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-i.html, https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/hello-world-rnn-83cd7105b767#.ozeai0fo8) do it differently. Instead, the target tensor has the same dimensions as the input tensor (**including bucket length**), there is **no overlap** in the buckets, and the state is cleared **only on epochs**. e.g

Method 2 (TBPTT (n,n)):

- [A,B,C,D,E] -> [B,C,D,E,F]
- [F,G,H,I,J] -> [G,H,I,J,K]
- [K,L,M,N,O] -> [L,M,N,O,P]
- [P,Q,R,S,T] -> [Q,R,S,T,U]
- [U,V,W,X,Y] -> [V,W,X,Y,Z]

I can understand this if internally tensorflow is evaluating the loss and doing TBPTT **at every step of the mini-sequence (i.e. bucket)** as opposed to just doing it at the end of the mini-sequence (bucket). What I don't get is, if that is the case, how far back are the errors propagated on an item halfway through a bucket? I.e. for the 2nd training example in this latter case, is [H] conditioned on [F,G] or [C,D,E,F,G] (as it clearly would be in the first method I explained).

This is assuming using tf's native rnn API such as tf.nn.dynamic_rnn.

[This article](https://r2rt.com/styles-of-truncated-backpropagation.html) confirms and illustrates really well that tensorflow does indeed calculate the loss and perform TBPTT at **every step of the mini-sequence / bucket, but only to the beginning of each bucket**.

TBPTT(n,1) for L=6, n=3 (the first method I was proposing)

[image: TBPTT(n,1) for L=6, n=3]

Tensorflow TBPTT for L=6, n=3

[image: Tensorflow TBPTT for L=6, n=3]

But my question still remains if this (i.e. the default tensorflow method) is a good way to do it (especially if we're only interested in learning a maximum of n timesteps dependency).

I understand that even though tf's TBPTT only propagates gradients to the beginning of the bucket, the state is preserved between buckets (i.e. see second diagram above), the final state of one minibatch is fed into the second. However, I don't understand how this will preserve continuity across **batches which are processed in parallel**. I.e. if we have a mini batch size of 2, one batch is

```
[[A,B,C,D,E] -> [B,C,D,E,F], [F,G,H,I,J] -> [G,H,I,J,K]]
```

[A,B,C,D,E] -> [B,C,D,E,F] is processed in parallel with [F,G,H,I,J] -> [G,H,I,J,K], there is no state being passed between them. So it becomes really crucial how the data is partitioned in batches, and one would not put adjacent buckets in the same batch, but in adjacent batches. i.e. it would be better to organise the batches as:

- batch1: [[A,B,C,D,E] -> [B,C,D,E,F], [K,L,M,N,O] -> [L,M,N,O,P]]
- batch2: [[F,G,H,I,J] -> [G,H,I,J,K], [P,Q,R,S,T] -> [Q,R,S,T,U]]

But even in this case are there not many discontinuities because of the parallel processing? e.g. [L] is not conditioned on [G,H,I,J,K].